# Can't find IISROOTFOLDER on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, installshield-2008

I'm using installshield to install my website to IIS, it works fine on windows server 2003, but while running on windows server 2008, it raise an error saying:

`Error 1606. Could not access network location {IISROOTFOLDER}`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Turn on logging  Setup.exe /Verbose"C:\Setup.log".  Will give you more info on the error.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your iisrootfolder.
In default website properites check home directory - local path.
Some times its missing changes so you could try vbscript custom action to get the "true" root directory:
Dim objIIsWebService
Set objIIsWebService = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT")
MsgBox objIIsWebService.Path